# How do I trigger the Apptentive rating prompt reminder?

Tags: android, apptentive

I just updated apptentive in my app to 1.5.0v. The rating prompt dialog is shown successfully when the conditions are true, but if the user clicks on "Remind me later", the rating prompt never is shown again.

I show the dialog, with the next code:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if (hasFocus
            && this instanceof SongActivity
            && InternalCache.getCounterApptentiveDialog() >= DOWNLOADS_TO_SHOW_APPTENTIVE) {

        boolean ret = Apptentive.engage(this, "init");
        if (ret) {
            System.out.println("GA-APPtentive");
            GAHelper.getInstance().apptentiveRateDialog(getClassName(),
                    getItemId());
        }
    }

}
```

Do I need something more in order to show the rating prompt dialog again?

Comment: Look here: http://www.apptentive.com/plans/

Comment: Thanks, I must be blind. I completely missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reminded to rate the app again according to the value in your Apptentive Rating Prompt interaction's settings:

[image: Re-prompted after X days]

If it's set to 10 days, you will need to wait 10 days after pressing "Remind Me Later" to be re-prompted. You can simulate this by moving your device clock forward.

The "reminder" interaction will only be triggered if you engage its event. This event is the same as the main event used to trigger the Rating Prompt.

[image: Event for reminder interaction]

iOS:

```
[[ATConnect sharedConnection] engage:@"testRatingFlow" fromViewController:self];
```

Android:

```
Apptentive.engage(this, "testRatingFlow").
```

Comment: I never thought you could move the clock in order to test it. They could use their server to get the current time... Thanks!

Comment: Apptentive supports offline scenarios; the interactions are downloaded and cached, and then the criteria for showing an interaction is evaluated on the device when that event is hit. So we use the device clock.